# Managing external jar dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I'v written a selenium framework which needs to be extended to the team. I've checked in the code in SVN. How can I make sure that external jars are added to build path and folder that folder by other team members? Basically I want to manage these dependencies better. Somebody said, Maven can take care of these so I tried to install m2eclipse plugin for eclipse 3.2 without any success. Can Maven solve this problem and is there any better way of managing it?

Answer (score 1):

Do the easy way: commit the jars into SVN. It will save everybody a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are amenable to using Eclipse, Maven, and m2eclipse, I would suggest using [SpringSource Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts).  It is an Eclipse based IDE with Maven and m2eclipse pre-bundled.  This bundling makes getting those three tools to work together very easy.

Comment: Thanks this seems much less hassle, but I cannot have this installed at workplace due to restricitons.